# Using a while loop with a Pandas DataFrame to increase a variable until a certain condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to calculate a ratio in a pandas dataframe column that utilizes a variable (x) and I want to determine the minimum value that x has to be to give me the ratio I am looking for.

I have posted an exert of the code below.

In this example I am trying to get the SGRS column to have ratios above the value of .3.

The main control of if this ratio gets above a .3 ratio is the variable x.

For the code example below, I want the minimum value that x has to be to return a ratio of .3.

I figured I would use a while statement to achieve this, but I seem to be missing something. I have included my code below and commented on the areas where I think something is wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#I create and set the column equal to 0 here so that it starts out automatically below my desired ratio threshold

ssdf['SGRS'] = 0

def min_throw_solver():
    #here i set the x value at 0 to start with
    x = 0

    while ssdf['SGRS'].min()<.3:

        #here is where I try to add 1 to the x value each time the calculation loops and yields a ratio less then
        #desired. I think this is where I have gone wrong.
        x+=1

        ssdf['SGRS'] = (((ssdf['cell_thickness']* ssdf['VShale']).rolling(fault_throw_cell_thickness).sum())/x)
        print ('x is currently',x)

        else:
            break
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there is any confusion and I will try to clarify

Comment: sample data to try and simulate would be good here. as another comment, looping through dataframe rows is very unefficient.

Comment: as far as you problem is concerned, it may very well be an issue where your 1 is an int and you're doing a flat/int division and get weird results. try initializing to 0.0 and add 1.0 instead of 1, or use float(x) where needed.

Comment: @MrE, I went ahead and took your suggestion and it worked! If you would like to answer my question, feel free to and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely cause of your problems is a kirk of Python when handling division of int and floats

You initialize `x` as an `int` (`x=0`)

and then do an `int` increment (`x +=1`)

and later you divide by `x` which ends up being a `float` divided by `int`, which usually turn up unexpected results.

try initializing x to a float with `x= 0.0`

and incrementing as a float with `x += 1.0`

and things should work as expected.